# i want to print content from a text file to html page

Tags: html, text

I have a text file which contains a number.
 I need to read this text file and display this number on a html page in a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at PHP and the `readfile()`, `fopen()` or `file_get_contents()` functions to read data from a file on your server.

Comment: @ramk: First, check that the server supports PHP. Then rename your `.html` file to `.php` and where you want to have your number appear in the code, add in `<?php readfile('<your_text_file>'); ?>`.

Beware that this is very very basic and you should invest in learning PHP (or scripting languages in general) thoroughly, especially when it comes to security, performance etc.